# Check if value exists on one date missing on next

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have one table with below column

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeohf.jpg)

I want to find missing nodes
Missing node definition: node present on day and missing the next day will be missing node on next day
In above example 111 will be missing on 2022-03-03
100 will be missing on 2022-03-03 and 2022-03-04

I have applied rank on snapshot partitioned by region but I m not sure how to proceed further

Comment: Provide sample data as textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (or at least as table-formatted text).

Answer (score 0):

> Missing node definition: node present on day and missing the next day

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table AS t2
                   WHERE t2.node = t1.node
                     AND t2.date = t1.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

The query returns "present day" row for which "the next day" row is absent.